# Why is this valid regex is not accepted by angular 2

Tags: regex, validation, angular

This regex string is valid (see https://regex101.com/r/cL2wT3/2):

```
^(\+27|27|0)\s?(\d{2})[-\s]?(\d{3})[-\s]?(\d{4})$
```

But for some reason Angular 2 throws:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./App class App - inline template:5:8 caused by: nothing to repeat
```

You can see this in the console as soon as you start typing in the text box of [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SLzGtBy0LhxDFuOEgYiV?p=preview).

**Why is this string not accepted by the validator?**

Comment: `/^^(+27|27|0)s?(d{2})[-s]?(d{3})[-s]?(d{4})$$/` see those `^^` and `$$` ?

Comment: You passed the regex as a string literal so you need to double the backslashes. Since such patterns are anchored by default you can omit anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping '\' is needed.
So it should be

```
^(\\+27|27|0)\\s?(\\d{2})[-\\s]?(\\d{3})[-\\s]?(\\d{4})$
```

Comment: Ah this is such a rookie error. Should have seen it. Thanks.